# Flip Faces by Instance in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a set of Instances, some of which I want to mirror randomly. This works fine, but when I mirror the instances, their normals also reverse.

This seems like an easy fix with the *Flip Faces* node but that only seems to operate on the face domain and I can not figure out how to access any instance level information on that domain.

So how to I flip the faces of my geometry based on the instance index?

[image: Instances after mirroring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should not have to worry about the orientation of the faces if you set up the setup as follows:

[image]

Instead of changing the points of the geometry here, I change the whole instance instead, which basically preserves the normals.

However, if you then use the node `Realize Instances`, the normals are flipped for some objects.

To avoid this problem, create a boolean value on the instance beforehand, which makes it clear that this instance should be flipped.

In this example I create this value via the *Dot Product*.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: That's pretty much the exact same way that I mirrored my instances. Sadly doing so does invert the normals as expected which you can see once you realize these instances. Add a realize instances node to your setup and you are basically where I am at right now.

Comment: @Waldo All right, I understand, that was my mistake. I have updated the answer, so it will work.

Comment: Cheers mate. I was pulling out my hair over this and the answer was so simple all along. I tried all the capture and sample nodes and wasn't able to associate the boolean correctly with the realized geometry.
This mirror part is only a small section of a much larger node I was working on. Storing which Instances were flipped in an Attribute and then flipping them back at the very end should be a perfect solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Waldo You're welcome!